# Using division operator in app insight analytics

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have the following app insights query :

```
let someResult=
customEvents | where name in ('SomeAction')
| parse customDimensions.someId with someId 
| parse customDimensions.sometaskId with someTaskId
| parse user_AuthenticatedId with user
| summarize max(timestamp) by user, someId , someTaskId
| join (
customEvents | where name in ('someAction')
| parse customDimensions.action with someAction
| parse customDimensions.someId with someId
| project someAction,someId
) on someId
| join (
customEvents
| where name in ('someResult')
| parse customDimensions.someId with someId 
| parse customDimensions.someIdsWithSomething with sometaskIds
| parse array_length(split(customDimensions.someIdsWithSomething ,',')) with someTaskCount
| distinct someId , sometaskIds,someTaskCount
| where sometaskIds<> ''
) on someId 
| summarize sumif(todouble(someTaskCount),someAction=="accept")/sum(todouble(someTaskCount));
```

How can i divide someResult by something here . For example i want the final result to be **someResult/10** . Thank you for the help.

Comment: Check out the useful operators documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/useful-operators.

Comment: I did but i am unable to do a simple division which the doc says it allows :(

Comment: In the query windows you can divide ```print 10/10```

Comment: One other quick question what if i want to divide the results from 2 different variables . For example : someResult/someAnotherResult

Comment: same concept ```let apple = 10;
let orange = 10;
print apple/orange```

Comment: @Rthomas529 that works in your example but not if the assigned value is a query result.

Comment: sure it does. Just assign the value of your query to a variable.

Comment: how can i just extract the result in that case ?

Comment: @Rthomas592 I must be doing something wrong then because I get an error about not being able to convert it to a scalar or something like that (away from keyboard so I cannot tell the exact message)

Comment: @Peter Bons  : Yep converting to scalar and a simple print works . Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let someResult=
customEvents | where name in ('SomeAction')
| parse customDimensions.someId with someId 
| parse customDimensions.sometaskId with someTaskId
| parse user_AuthenticatedId with user
| summarize max(timestamp) by user, someId , someTaskId
| join (
customEvents | where name in ('someAction')
| parse customDimensions.action with someAction
| parse customDimensions.someId with someId
| project someAction,someId
) on someId
| join (
customEvents
| where name in ('someResult')
| parse customDimensions.someId with someId 
| parse customDimensions.someIdsWithSomething with sometaskIds
| parse array_length(split(customDimensions.someIdsWithSomething ,',')) with someTaskCount
| distinct someId , sometaskIds,someTaskCount
| where sometaskIds<> ''
) on someId 
| summarize summarized = sumif(todouble(someTaskCount),someAction=="accept")/sum(todouble(someTaskCount));
someResult 
| project summarized / 10
```

I could not test it since I do not have those custom dimensions but it is based from this working/tested example:

```
let someResult = requests
| summarize summarized = count();
someResult 
| project summarized / 10
```

Comment: Yes this works . One other quick question what if i want to divide the results from 2 different variables . For example : someResult/someAnotherResult

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps someone, as this SO question shows up as the top result but doesn't answer the question. I determined something like this from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40003713/azure-application-insights-query-how-to-calculate-percentage-of-total):

```
let authRequests = requests | where operation_Name contains "Auth";
let countNon500s = toscalar(authRequests | where resultCode !startswith "5" | count);
let countAll = toscalar(authRequests | count);
let percent = 100*todouble(todouble(countNon500s) / todouble(countAll));
print todecimal(percent)
```

The three important parts are:

- you need to convert the values to scalar values (otherwise they are tables).
- you need to convert the resulting percentage to doubles (otherwise they are 1 or 0)
- you need to use 'print' to output to a tabular form (or extend a column)